# How can I add metadata to MP3s for Windows Media player from a script

Tags: vbscript, metadata, windows-media-player

I previously asked this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/51706/how-can-i-add-metadata-to-mp3s-for-windows-media-player), but now I've gotten lazy and I'm trying to figure out how to do it from script (vbscript specifically).  Specifically what I want to know is:

> How can I set Artist, Song Title,
>   Genre, etc on a mp3 file from
>   vbscript?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[Here are instructions.](http://www.motobit.com/tips/detpg_change-id3-tags-script/)

There's a DLL required which can be gotten from freely available Creative Blaster drivers.

Also see [this project](http://id3lib.sourceforge.net/) - seems to support many languages including vbscript

If you're not wedded to vbscript idea, Perl has a very nice library MP3::Tag or somesuch (just google for perl+mp3+tag); assuming you're game for installing Windows Perl (Strawberry or Active Perl)

Comment: Your first link doesn't seem related, but I like the library (id3lib).  Know of a good set of instructions for using it with vbscript?

Comment: Sorry, nothing more than at the link :(